# connect db2 using python with securityMechanism=13

Tags: python, encryption, jdbc, db2

I'm trying to connect db2 using python but I don't know how to set the securityMechanism=13 property correctly can you please tell me how to do this?

```
import jaydebeapi

conn_src = jaydebeapi.connect(
    'com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver',
    'jdbc:db2://host:port/dbname',{"encryptionAlgorithm":"2",'securityMechanism':'13', 'user':'username',"password":'pass'},'',
)

cursor=conn_src.cursor()
```

ERROR MESSAGE:

> com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlExceptionPyRaisable:
> com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlException: [jcc][t4][10441][12439][3.69.66]
> encryptionAlgorithm can only be set with securityMechanism
> ENCRYPTED_PASSWORD_SECURITY and ENCRYPTED_USER_AND_PASSWORD_SECURITY.
> ERRORCODE=-4450, SQLSTATE=null

I would be happy to use ibm_db, but I did not find a way to set securityMechanism=13.

Comment: Please edit your question to add more facts.  Which Db2-platform (z/os , i-series,  linux/unix/windows)  hosts the database to which you try to connect?.  How is authentication configured on the target environment? Which jdbc driver+version are you using?  Why can't you use the CLIDRIVER and ibm_db ?  Please include the __exact__ error message details.

Comment: Please edit your question to answer __all__ the requested clarifications

Comment: For Db2 servers that run on Linux/Unix/Windows , the python `ibm_db` module with clidriver (or other IBM supplied equivalent), supports connection-strings that have the AUTHENTICATION parameter matching the value of that parameter on the Db2-instance.

Answer (score 0):

Have received the same Error when trying to connect via Jaydebeapi, but when I tried to connect with ibm_db_dbi it works without any error.

Below script works fine and no need to mention 'securityMechanism' explicitly.

```
#Header
from ibm_db_dbi import connect

#Connection string
conn_src = connect("DATABASE=<DB_Name>;
                    HOSTNAME=<Host_Name>;
                    PORT=50000;PROTOCOL=TCPIP;
                    UID=<username>;PWD=<password>;", "", "")
```

Comment: OP has a concern for explicitly stating securityMechanism=13, so it'd be nice if you could elaborate on why it is unnecessary this way.